# Spring Data MongoDB - Randomly select documents but in order of an enum

Tags: spring, mongodb, kotlin, mongodb-query, spring-data

I want my query to randomly select 3 entries, but it should always select all entries with status "NEW" first, only if there are no entries in status “NEW” anymore it then should select entries in status "IN_PROGRESS", then "PAUSED".

My plan was to filter by status first, then sort the filtered document in ascending order by the status field with **sort()** (which puts all “NEW” entries to the top, “IN_PROGRESS” in the middle and “PAUSED” at the very bottom), then limit the result to the top 3 documents with **limit()**, then randomly select 3 documents from this remaining set with **sample()**.

This is my code, however it’s not sorting by enum correctly. What did I miss here?

```kotlin
enum class BookStatus {
    NEW,
    IN_PROGRESS,
    PAUSED,
    DONE,
    DISMISSED,
;

    companion object {
        val allToBeRead = listOf(
            NEW,
            IN_PROGRESS,
            PAUSED
        )
    }
}

fun findAllToBeRead(size: Int): List<Book> {
    return
      mongoTemplate
        .aggregate<Book, Book>(
          newAggregation(
            match(
              where(STATUS).`in`(BookStatus.allToBeRead),
            ),
            sort(
              Sort.by(
                Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, STATUS),
              )),
            Aggregation.limit(size),
            sample(size),
          ),
        )
        .map { it.toModel() }
  }
```

Some examples for better understanding:

```kotlin
**Example 1**

**Source Data**

book1(status=IN_PROGRESS)
book2(status=PAUSED)
book3(status=NEW)
book4(status=NEW)
book5(status=NEW)
book6(status=NEW)

**Result**

book4(status=NEW)
book5(status=NEW)
book3(status=NEW)

**Example 2**

**Source Data**

book1(status=IN_PROGRESS)
book2(status=PAUSED)
book3(status=NEW)
book4(status=NEW)

**Result**

book4(status=NEW)
book3(status=NEW)
book1(status=IN_PROGRESS)
```